# metallb speaker crashloopbackoff

Tags: kubernetes, metallb

I want to expose a pod app to port 80, for that i have installed Metallb and configured a load balancer like this:

metallb-config.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.150
```

loadbalancer.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: loadbalancer-watchdog
spec:
  selector:
    part: watchdog
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 10069
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

But when i do `kubectl get svc` the loadBalancer keep appearing as  and if i check metallb with `kubectl -n metallb-system get all i can see this:

[image]

If i check the logs:

[image]

Has something to do with my config or do i miss some step in the configuration of Metallb?

EDIT:

Output of `kubectl -n kube-system get pods`
[image]

Apparently the coredns are down and also the storage.

Comment: share output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system. Is there a firewall between the kubernetes nodes?

Comment: Added the output of the command `kubectl -n kube-system get pods`

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez Could you please share your logs and outputs as a text instead of screenshots? It is hard to work with something like that.

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happened to me but it did not start because it collided with a docker swarm port, just run

`docker swarm leave -f`

and try again